# notepad++ tab to left

Tags: notepad++, code-formatting, key-bindings

If I press tab the line moves to right, what I must press to move line to left?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>

[Here](http://www.keyxl.com/aaacd5a/43/Notepad-Plus-text-editor-software-keyboard-shortcuts.htm) is a list of shortcuts for notepad++

Comment: Thanks to this answer i learned the <kbd> tag. lol. Upvote just for that

Comment: How can I set the step to be 2 spaces instead of (default) 4 spaces?

Answer (score 18):

The shortcut you are looking for is:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

To check or modify your shortcuts you can go to:

```
Macro -> Modify Shortcut/Delete Macro...
```

Comment: How can I set the step to be 2 spaces instead of (default) 4 spaces?